# Kotlin Extension Function on Observable<T>.subscribe does not work

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to write an extension function for Observable.subscribe which automatically logs errors.

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.subscribeAndLogE(onNext: Consumer<in T>): Disposable =
    subscribe(onNext, ErrorConsumer())
```

The ErrorConsumer works and presumably logs the error, but `subscribeAndLogE` does not accept lambdas like `.subscribe()` does.

```
observer.subscribe { 
                //works
           }

observer.subscribeAndLogE { 
                //does not work
           }
```

It says:

[image: error]

With that OnboardingScreen being whichever value `T` would normally be.

I don't see the original `Consumer<in T>` in `Observable` doing anything special to accept lambdas. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a parameter of type `Consumer` to the function. You need to pass a function for the lambda syntax to work. This would work the way you want to:

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.subscribeAndLogE(onNext: (it : T) -> Unit): Disposable =
        subscribe({ onNext(it) },{ throwable -> Log(throwable) })
```

and use it like so:

```
observer.subscribeAndLogE { 
                //works
           }
```

Comment: This does not work either. The subscribe function inside the extension function says it requires a Consumer, not a Unit.

Comment: Are you using the correct subscribe function? Because there is one which doesn't require a Consumer, instead it takes two functions.
https://i.imgur.com/gBCNc4k.png

Comment: The fact that I was passing it an ErrorConsumer instead of an Error function was causing the issue. Thanks. :)